# Trying to hide fixed navigation bar behind cover image while scrolling with z-index

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I have 2 navigation bars, 1 is fixed other is not. After the fixed navbar comes a cover image. And i want the fixed navbar to be behind it until it ends. But when i used `z-index: -1;` then i won't be able to click on it afterwards... And if i use `z-index: 10` on the cover part and on the static navbar and use a higher index for the fixed navbar, then I don't get the result i want.

css:

```
#fixed-nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1 OR 9;
}

/** STATIC navigation **/

#top-nav {
    z-index:10
}

/** COVER header **/

#cover {
    background-image: url(../img/cover.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 10;
}

/* content after cover picture */

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

Markup:

```
<header id="fixed-nav" class="navigation">
    <nav>
        ...
    </nav>
</header>
<header id="top-nav" class="navigation">
    <nav>
        ...
    </nav>
</header>
<header id="cover">

</header>

<div id="wrapper">
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Provide a link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  `position: absolute;` the cover

```css
#fixed-nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:  1;
    font-size: 30px;
    
}

/** STATIC navigation **/

#top-nav {
    
    font-size: 30px;
   
}

/** COVER header **/

#cover {
    background-image: url(http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--Y4iAgmph--/1282803868846423983.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<header id="top-nav" class="navigation">
    <nav>
       <a href="google.com">not fixed</a>
       <a href="google.com">not fixed</a>
       <a href="google.com">not fixed</a>
    </nav>
</header>
<header id="cover">

</header> 

<header id="fixed-nav" class="navigation">
    <nav>
        <a href="twitter.com">fixed nav bar</a>
        <a href="twitter.com">fixed nav bar</a>
        <a href="twitter.com">fixed nav bar</a>
    </nav>
</header>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```