# Z-index not hiding content under fixed navigation bar while scrolling

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am learning CSS and HTML. While creating a website, I have to create a fixed navigation bar. However, when I scroll, the scrolled content shows over the navigation bar. Here is the HTML (Please ignore so many paragraphs. I had to make it scrollable):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./minimum_problem.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">

      <div id="header-wrapper">
        <header id="header">
          <div id="header-img">
            <img
              id="logo"
              src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png"
              alt="Original Trombones logo"
            />
          </div>
  
          <div id="nav-bar">
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-link"> 
                <a href="#Features" alt="Features of Trombone">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-link">How It Works</li>
              <li class="nav-link">Pricing</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
      

      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
      </div>

      
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  
  #header-wrapper {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  
  header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 3vh auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  #content-wrapper {
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  
  #logo {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #nav-bar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .nav-link {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
  
  .nav-link > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
```

I read about stacking context ([z-index is not working with position fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524618/z-index-is-not-working-with-position-fixed)), and therefore created new  elements with "header-wrapper" and "content-wrapper" to make them siblings and provide proper z-index so that header-wrapper overrides content-wrapper. Still doesn't work.

Here is what happens:

[image: Notice the paragraphs on top of the navigation bar]

Also looked at other solutions which didn't work as well. [Trying to hide fixed navigation bar behind cover image while scrolling with z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663630/trying-to-hide-fixed-navigation-bar-behind-cover-image-while-scrolling-with-z-in)

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (i.e., elements with a `position` value other than the default `static`.) Which, at least based on the snippet you have shown us, neither #header-wrapper nor #content-wrapper would actually be.

Comment: @CBroe, learnt something new. Thank you. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue then.

Comment: @CBroe Added a minimal reproducible problem. Please take a look. Also in the above snippet, `header` has `fixed` position. I have also added it to `header-wrapper`. That also doesn't work.

Comment: As soon as `#header-wrapper` gets a position (doesn't have to be fixed, relative works as well), the z-index issue should be solved. Only, you will probably not actually _notice_ that, as long as you don't give the header a background ... right now, their background is transparent, so the content below them is of course still visible through them.

Comment: @CBroe Yes that was the issue. The background was transparent. Once I gave it a colour, the issue was resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For z-index to work you need to specify a value for the `position` property. The two elements where you are trying to specify a z-index do not have a position specified. You need to set the `position` to `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed` for the content-wrapper and header-wrapper. You can read more about the `position` property and possible values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). In your case, if you want the wrapper to be fixed as well, I would suggest setting the `header-wrapper` to `fixed` and the `content-wrapper` to `relative`.

Comment: I did that. Added `fixed` to `header-wrapper` and `relative` to `content-wrapper`. Also removed `fixed` position from `header` element. But it didn't work.

Comment: @Sankrit It's possible the margin on your header is causing the issue. Instead of using a margin on the header, use padding on the header-wrapper.

Comment: Added a minimal reproducible problem. Please take a look. Also in the above snippet, `header` has `fixed` position. I have also added it to `header-wrapper`. That also doesn't work.

Comment: @Sankrit Remove the margin from the header, and add it to the padding on the header-wrapper instead. Add fixed position to header, and set position to relative for the header-wrapper. Remove the z-index from the content-wrapper,  but leave the z-index for the header-wrapper. Lastly, make sure there is no parent element's with z-indexes.